# Multivariate or Multi-level meta-analysis with metafor?

Tags: metafor

I am conducting a meta-analysis across 196 studies. Each study reports one or more of "6 outcomes", which are measured using one or more of "3 factors".

Now I am unsure how to code the random effects. I was thinking about two alternatives:

A multivariate model such as:

```
res <- rma.mv(yi, V,slab = study, random=~Outcome_Factor|study, data=dat, method="ML")
```

A three-level model such as:

```
res <- rma.mv(yi, vi,slab = study, random=~1|study/Outcome_Factor,data=dat, method="ML")
```

What would be more appropriate?

Thank you very much in advance.

Kind regards

Lisa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are different 'parameterizations' of the same model. See here for an extensive discussion of this:

https://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/analyses:konstantopoulos2011

So in the end, the two models are identical, the results are just expressed in different ways.